Passing In-Memory Specification to Repository
I am working on my DDD know-what/how and have the following questions related to the Specification Pattern, the Repository Pattern, persistence agnosticism, and performance.
Consider, for the sake of simplicity:

IAggreate, Customer,
IRepository, CustomerRepository,
Not using entity framework or any ORM in any way,
Using a relational database for persistence,
A specification which is valid only when the Customer’s first name equals the parameter X.

1 Is it not necessary for CustomerRepository to load into memory
from the database all Customer records to evaluate the specification?
2 If 1 is true, is this recommendable considering performance?
3 If 2 is a no, how should this be solved given the constraints? By not using the Specification pattern after all?
Extrapolating from the example, the problem I see is that the argument for X (the particular first name) will not be passed to the SQL WHERE clause, which causes potentially infeasible memory demands in the application. I assume it does not make sense for the repository to interpret the specification rather than executing it in some way. The specification would probably encapsulate the argument for X such that the repository could not get at it anyway. Also, interpreting the specification in the repository would drastically reduce the value of unit testing the specification.

Why do you think the Specification wouldn't be translated to a (parametrized) SQL query by the repository? The Repository Pattern also doesnt' rely on complicated Specification support – often, you just need a plain function parameter. For example Customer[] findByFirstName(string firstName) => return execute("select * from customers where first_name = ?", firstName). (In practice I'd also add support for order by to get deterministic results, and some kind of pagination.)

I’d like to think I’ve taken my time with this question. However, if anybody else feels like downvoting it, please let me know about the justification for it, so I can improve the question

@amon I think so because it seems to me that this would defeat the purpose of the specification pattern. For instance, unit testing the specification would not make much sense if the repository unfolds the specification to produce SQL. In their DDD fundamentals course on Pluralsight, Stevie Smith and Julie Lerman posit that creating methods as you propose bloats the repository interface quickly, violating SOLID. Kindly keep “for the sake of simplicity” in mind. I guess your answer is: The Specification pattern is not intended for this. Right?

@STHA: is your question about getting all customers from a database which fulfill the boolean logic of a specification object? For a single customer object with a single specification object (which is how your question can be interpreted), I don't see any problem.

@DocBrown, yes. That’s one incarnation of it. However, without interpreting the specification in the repository to produce WHERE firstName LIKE foo, the database would have to return ALL customer records over the network to the application. That is a problem from a performance perspective, I think.

I’ve added my explanation to @amon in the question, since I am starting to suspect I have some invalid assumption somewhere.

I've looked up the description of Specifications in Evan's DDD book, and it suggests an entire range of implementation approaches – from giving the spec an asSQL() method (discouraged), over using ORMs or having the spec call back into lower-level methods of the repository, to doing more complicated filtering in-memory. In one example, a specification is sketched out with builder-style code criteria = new Criteria(); criteria.equals(TradeOrder.SECURITY, "WCOM"); criteria.equals(TradeOrder.ACCOUNT, "123"); orders = tradeOrdersRepo.matching(criteria) which suggests dynamic query building.

@amon Thanks a lot! I do not remember him being this specific but I will look it up when I get back home (where my copy is).

"Also, interpreting the specification in the repository would drastically reduce the value of unit testing the specification." Why can't you write a code (a service) that transforms spec into sql, regardless of repository? And test that separately?

@freakish I could. With that in place however, I struggle to see the benefit of the Specification pattern. At that point, why not just add FindByFirstName(string firstName) to the repository interface?

This thread re-phrased and addressed my concerns: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/ddd-bulk-operations/#comment-4679130000

That is, you can either use a ORM which accepts C# expressions as parameters, implement a custom expression-to-SQL translator in the Infrastructure layer, or couple the Domain layer to SQL persistence. You cannot have your cake and eat it too. One question remains however: Recalling the example, if you use a ORM, will all Customer records not be returned over the network anyway?

@STHA that would be beneficial if you had some potentially complex queries to process. Coming from users. Otherwise there is no benefit, no. That's why you will rarely see this pattern utilized in real life.

@STHA: an ORM is rarely the solution here. The spec pattern helps most when you have to implement boolean logic which is independent from persistence, regardless whether the persistence is realized with raw SQL or some ORM.

Your question is a classic one: DDD suggests to implement most business logic in the domain model, in an object-oriented fashion, using the programming language of your domain objects. But for a few certain use cases like querying some data from a large set from a database, this approach will hit its limits - mostly performance wise, especially when compared with the right kind of SQL query.
Those are the cases where you probably have to make a trade-off and implement some logic in SQL. As you wrote already in a comment, a repo function FindByFirstName(string firstName) might be a good idea for this. You wrote

With that in place however, I struggle to see the benefit of the Specification pattern

Well, I would not throw that pattern or the DDD ideas generally over board just because I may have to optimize a few parts of my program and cut a few corners. DDD is an approach for complex domains with complex business logic - querying a few objects/records by something which is so simple that it can be expressed an almost trivial WHERE condition in SQL is not the best example of where DDD will show its benefits.
Think of specification objects for more interesting cases:

testing if a customer is valid for some discount, where the spec object is a parametric discount calculator

test if the customer of a bank is eligible for a credit by some credit validation logic

or think of cases where one does start with some prefiltered customer objects already in memory, a subset of reasonable size, and now needs to filter this set of objects more finegrained


These are all cases where the logic can be placed perfectly inside the domain model, with no repository access or database involved.

Just to extend the opening points of this answer: the elegance of architectural patterns often struggles with the practicalities of real world performance (or, rephrased, the wastefulness of doing your operations the long way round). Unless you are striving for theoretical elegance above all else, at some point you're going to need to make compromises in order to optimize your specific use case. The key skill is in identifying which compromises to make, in a way that they net you a high benefit without leading you too far astray from your architecture.
